# Two queries in one transaction with rollback

Tags: mysql, transactions, try-catch, commit, rollback

i want to cancel the two queries if there is a failure in one of two, is my tests that execute the first query although the second aground

```
public function testCommit(){

        $host = "localhost";
        $db = "agm_gs";
        $user = "root";
        $password = "";
        $conn;
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

        $sql1 = 'INSERT INTO livreur (id_livreur, code_livreur, nom_livreur, pre_livreur)  VALUES (NULL, \'L001\', \'nom1\', \'pre1\')';
        $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO otherTable XXXXXXXXXXincorrect queryXXXXXXXX';

        try
        {
            $conn->begin_transaction();
            $conn->autocommit(FALSE);

            $conn->query($sql1);
            $conn->query($sql2);

            $conn->commit();
            echo 'Sucess transaction';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $conn->rollback();
            echo ' Error transaction <br />' . $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

and this my result of insert

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
$sql1 = 'INSERT INTO livreur 
id_livreur, code_livreur, nom_livreur, pre_livreur)  
VALUES (NULL, \'L001\', \'nom1\', \'pre1\'),
(NULL, \'L002\', \'nom2\', \'pre2\')';
```

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas.

Comment: i already tested this.... but the problem if both requettes on two different tables for exemple $sql1 = 'INSERT INTO livreur (id_livreur, code_livreur, nom_livreur, pre_livreur)  VALUES (NULL, \'L001\', \'nom1\', \'pre1\')'; and $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO otherTable(id_livreur, code_livreur, nom_livreur, pre_livreur)  VALUES (NULL, \'L002\', \'nom2\', \'pre2\')';

Comment: use 2 different insert query in this case @isom

Comment: yes i used 2 differt insert query but I want to cancel the fierst if the second is unsuccessful

Comment: in this case if  second is unsuccessful. delete  inserted record on first table

Comment: thank you but I want to do an automatic rollback in catch block